# DIV with background image

Tags: javascript, asp.net

We have applied the backgroud image(round corner image from web site) for DIV control. and then dynamically added more statement in DIV control.

How we will increase the height and width for the image?

Please give us some suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using javascript you can change the background-size.
**Note - It's a CSS3 feature.**

Within style tag

```
.div_class_name
 {
 background:url(img_flwr.gif);
 background-size:80px 60px;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 }
```

when content changes in div you can use the following syntax to change the size

```
document.getElementById("eleId").style.backgroundSize="60px 80px" ;
```

Comment: CSS support depends on browser , almost all latest browsers have support for CSS3.You just write the css and javascript code , if the browser supports CSS3 the background-size will change else it will remain as it is.

Answer (score 1):

Try using css3

```
.div {
background: #eee;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Or you will need to do all kinds of messy stuff like resizing the background image, or splitting them off into 'corners' and all that... a huge headache

Comment: Id agree but it depends what browsers they are targetting, we often work with browsers which do not support this, at the moment for some projects I would still recommend using images.

Comment: in addition there are JS libraries to mimick this functionality for old, useless browsers like IE7 and IE8 :)